# How to pass on path of ZLIB to ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, julia

Executing, both:
a)`$/home/julia/displayImage.jl`
b) `julia> /home/julia/displayImage.jl`
throw error:
`...could not load library ...deps/usr/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so" lib64/libz.so.1: version ZLIB_1.2.9`, 
where displayImage.jl, is:

```
#! /opt/julia-1.1.0/bin/julia
using Images, TestImages, FileIO, Colors, ImageView;
function displayImage(path::String)
    img = nothing;
    if isfile(path)
        img = load(path);
        imshow(img);
    else
        info("ERROR: While loading image!");
    end
end
```

the same code works when each command is copied,  pasted and executed at julia prompt during the ImageMagick's build session but not after exit from the session!

It is observed that:
 a)julia is not using the ZLIB installed in its deps folder after build session of ImageMagick. 
b)the os and julia packages CodecZlib, Conda, ZipFile, ImageMagick... have different versions of ZLIB.

Please advise me on a) how to pass on ZLIB path which is inside the folder of package, ImageMagick while executing at shell prompt and b) also using single updated version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing the followong line at shell prompt resolves the issue for the session.

```
$export LD_LIBRARY=/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/ImageMagick/deps/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

where the first path is of ZLIB inside ImageMagick package.